# Python not entering in for

Tags: python, for-loop

Why the unique[1] is never accessed in the second for???
unique is an array of strings.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in range(len(unique)):
         #   print unique[i]   #prints all the items in the array        
            for row in reader:
                print unique[i] # always prints the first item unique[0]
                if row[1]==unique[i]:        
                    print row[1], row[0] # prints only the unique[0] stuff
```

Thank you

Comment: You should replace `for i in range(len(unique)):` and `unique[i]` with `for item in unique:` and `item`. With almost no exceptions, you should never write `range(len(x))`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan same situation. It only takes the first item in the second for

Comment: I'm not proposing that as a solution to the problem, but rather as general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be useful to go through the program flow.

First, it will assign `i=0`, then it will read **the entire** CSV file, printing `unique[0]` for each line in the CSV file, then after it **finishes** reading the CSV file, it will go to the second iteration, assigning `i=1`, and then since the program has finished reading the file, it won't enter `for row in reader:`, hence it exits the loop.

#### Further Clarification

The `csv.reader(f)` won't actually read the file until you do `for row in reader`, and after that it has nothing more to read. If you want to read the file multiple times, then read it into a list first beforehand, like this:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        rows = [row for row in reader]
        for i in range(len(unique)):
            for row in rows:
                print unique[i]
                if row[1]==unique[i]:        
                    print row[1], row[0]
```

Comment: The file is read BEFORE the for. rihgt? So in your opinion how may I solve this?? thanks @justhalf

Comment: @Alberto: file and CSV readers are lazy, which saves memory but also means that you only get one pass at the file.

Comment: So in that case what is your solution??

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you really want to print the whole CSV file for each element in `unique` array, then my edited answer would answer your question. Otherwise, probably the answer by @bveb333 is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have better luck if you change your nested structure to:

```
import csv
res = {}
for x in unique:
    res[x] = []
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for i in range(len(unique)):
             #   print unique[i]   #prints all the items in the array        
                if row[1]==unique[i]:  
                    res[unique[i]].append([row[1],row[0]])      
                    #print row[1], row[0] # prints only the unique[0] stuff
for x in unique:
    print res[x]
```

Comment: This thing does not work. I need to look in row for each item in unique and not the opposite. Sorry